# Does the C programming language support SQL Statements

Tags: sql, c

I have a flyport wifi microchip and it runs on c code.  I wanted to update a database with it.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to send sql statements to my database with it. Does anyone know how to do this in C?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Honestly that is fine if you want to down vote me... But Please explain why you do so in the comments.  I do in fact want to go about posting questions properly.  I also want to express that I do not just get on stackOverflow and just post a question without first trying to figure it out myself.  I just happen to not find somethings that are apparently easy to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C itself is not capable of doing this. You will need a library providing a `C`-interface.